# Click Button, Add New Row to Form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am in the process of learning Oracle APEX version 18. For my first project, I created a form that is generated from a view which is based on two tables:

[image]

When the form is submitted, the following trigger is called so that the data can be inserted into its correct table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "TRG_VIEW_PERSON_COMPUTER_INSRT" 
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON view_person_computer
    DECLARE
        duplicate_info EXCEPTION;
        PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (duplicate_info, -00001);
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PERSON (
            ID,
            FIRST_NAME,
            LAST_NAME,
            EMAIL,
            PHONE
        ) VALUES (
            SEQPERSON.NEXTVAL,
            :NEW.FIRST_NAME,
            :NEW.LAST_NAME,
            :NEW.EMAIL,
            :NEW.PHONE
        );
        INSERT INTO COMPUTER (
            ID,
            PERSON_ID,
            MAKE,
            MODEL,
            CPU,
            RAM,
            HARD_DRIVE
        ) VALUES (
            SEQCOMPUTER.NEXTVAL,
            SEQPERSON.CURRVAL,
            :NEW.MAKE,
            :NEW.MODEL,
            :NEW.CPU,
            :NEW.RAM,
            :NEW.HARD_DRIVE
        );
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN duplicate_info THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
                    num=> -20107,
                    msg=> 'Duplicate customer or project id'
                );
    END trg_view_person_computer_insrt;
```

Currently, the "Add Another Computer" button is not functional. So a person can only have one computer associated with them. For the next phase of the project, I want to make the button functional but my knowledge of APEX is still very limited.

The goal: when the "Add Another Computer" button is clicked, it should duplicate the computer related text fields so that the user can input another computer. What is the best way to add this functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can use interactive grid to do this functionality. I think it works perfectly in this case.

Answer (score 2):

No problem in doing what you're doing (if you really want to do that), but - why reinventing the wheel?

Being on Apex 18.x, I'd suggest you to use its capabilities and create a **master-detail** page. You'll find it within the Create Page Wizard.

- set PERSON table to be a master
- set COMPUTER table to be a detail
- let the Wizard do the rest

Doing so, you'll have it up and running in a matter of seconds. Both blocks (regions) will be updateable interactive grids which will let you enter new rows (using the **Add row** button), update or delete existing ones, Oracle will pay attention to foreign keys, ... shortly, you won't believe your own eyes.

As I've said: you can do it *your way* for educational purposes, but that's the *hard way*.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Is there a way to style a master-detail page exactly like the form in my post above? Also, this will be a publicly available form and so it should not be populated with data on page load, as the master-detail page does. If these features are not possible, any suggestions on implementing my original question? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I can tell, the master-detail form created by the Wizard uses interactive grid. Previous Apex versions would use a Tabular form layout, I presume. Can you make it look like you wan? Maybe, but I don't think that Wizard will do that. You could try to "copy" processes from the Wizard-created page to your own attempt and see whether you can make it work. On the other hand, perhaps you could abandon Apex and switch to some other tool which is capable of creating web pages and see whether it offers what you're looking for.